# few "easy" questions about function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Examine the function $y = x^2 - 4x + 3$ and determine:

- if the curve has a maximum or minimum point?
- the function's zeroes
- the function's line of symmetry,
- coordinates of the turning point

Comment: Have you calculus techniques at hand?

Comment: Have you tried completing the square?

Comment: Note that you can easily factor the function into $(x-3)$ $(x-1)$. Your zeroes should be obvious from that. And, I second David Mitra's comment.  Some derivatives would make this process for extrema slightly easier.

Comment: Can you graph it?

Answer (score 3):

To answer all your questions, try to complete the square so that the function is written in the form
$$y = a(x-b)^2 + c.$$
In this form, it is easy to determine whether the function has a maximum or a minimum (this will depend on the value of $a$), the zeros (this will depend on $a$, $b$, and $c$), the line of symmetry (depends on $b$), and the turning point (again, depends on $b$).